# When a company drops or deaffiliates with a representative/promoter

Tags: single-word-requests

It is often the case that a company sponsoring, endorsing, or otherwise affiliated with an individual, will "drop" their support of said individual for PR reasons, usually in the case of offensive or controversial remarks that the company wants to distance themselves from.

> XYZ company announced their intention to ["drop"] John Smith in light of his controversial remarks.
>
> XYZ company ["dropped"] John Smith in light of his controversial remarks.

I am looking for a word more specifically referring to "the termination of a contract", i.e. complete severance of any relations between the company and the individual, than the less-specific word "drop".

Words that come to mind are "de-affiliate", "renounce", "disavow", but so far I think "repudiate" works best.

Comment: There are all sorts of terms that might be used, depending on how the PR folks want it to sound.

Comment: Contracts get cancelled.